# Replace multiple values - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

```
       table 1                                     table 2

+---------+------------+                    +---------+------------+
| post_id | meta_value |                    |    ID   | post_title |
+---------|------------+                    +---------|------------+
|    1    |   value_a  |                    |    1    | title_abc  |
+---------|------------+                    +---------|------------+
|    2    |   value_b  |                    |    2    | title_xyh  |
+---------|------------+                    +---------|------------+
|    3    |   value_c  |                    |    3    | title_jer  |
+---------|------------+                    +---------|------------+
| .....   | .........  |                    |   ..... |   .......  |
+---------|------------+                    +---------|------------+
|   999   | value_xyzw |                    |   999   | title_bhw  |
+---------|------------+                    +---------|------------+
```

I have 2 tables. I try to replace the records from `post_title` (table 2)  with `meta_value` {table 1).

Example:

`value_a` replace `title_abc`

`value_b` replace `title_xyh`

`value_c` replace `title_jer`

............

etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `update` with a `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.post_id = t2.id
    set t1.meta_value = t2.post_title;
```

Comment: i try to add another condition: `meta_key = custom_title`. `meta_key` is another column in table1

Comment: Ok. I got it: `and t2.meta_key like 'custom_title'`

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.metavalue = table2.post_title 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```